# How to make whole table as a link?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a whole table as link?

I have a table which displays some statistical data, I wish to add up an additional functionality to this table so that .. when a user clicks on **any part of the table**, webpage should guide him/her to new page.

Comment: Did <a href="#"><table>...</table></a> not work?

Comment: yes, but causes validation error!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really possible. However, it can be easily emulated with JavaScript. You just need to asign an `onclick` event handler to the table and make it change the `document.location` property:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById("my-table");
myTable.onclick = function(){
    document.location.href = "http://example.com";
}
```

You can also provide and adequate cursor with some CSS:

```
table#my-table{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put a `<a href="#"></a>` around your table

Answer (score 0):

The [biggerLink](http://www.ollicle.com/projects/jquery/biggerlink/) plugin for jQuery does pretty much what Álvaro G. Vicario suggested and it has a few extra niceties such as `title` attribute handling and `:hover` handling.